# Deno not recognised in VS Code's Terminal

Tags: javascript, server, backend, deno

I'm sorry, I got this trouble on my VS Code terminal, Deno isn't recognized:
[image: doesn't recognized on vs code]

But when I try to do it in my Windows command prompt in the exact same path, it works:
[image: worked on windows command prompt]

Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Have you tried restarting vscode and windows?

Comment: try running vscode in administrator mode

Comment: If nothing works check if deno is added to system environment path

Comment: restart vscode.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how you installed Deno, but I am assuming you did it using Windows Command while your VS Code was running, therefore it have a different terminal session.

If that's the case the VS Code terminal won't find the `deno` executable because it is a different session and it needs load from the PATH again.

Restart VS Code and see what happens.

If you want to be sure print the PATH variable and confirm that `deno` is in there.

```
echo %PATH%
```

Checkout [deno_install](https://github.com/denoland/deno_install) for more installation options.

I personally like to use Choco to managed my Windows packages (I thought I run mostly WSL).

```
choco install deno
```